# how to escape form filtering for certain fields using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter form validation and i have set some rules for my form fields. When i type %50 or %test% , I don't get the rest of the texts posted  after the first occurrence of % character.
Please help how to solve this.

Comment: share your rules or controller

Answer (score 0):

```
remove the 'xss_clean' rule.
```

consider your text box /textarea's name would be, 'mine'

```
$this->form_validation('mine','Mine', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

to

```
$this->form_validation('mine','Mine', 'trim|required');
```

xss clean prevent scripts and encode.

Comment: I have not applied xss_clean rule. I want all texts to be posted whatever i type.

Comment: can you post the rules which are applied in your controller?
Also the print_r($_POST);

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules("details","Description","trime|required");

Comment: tanx for your response, i printed the $_POST, but still i dont get the text which i have typed. The point is when i type % sign befor any number suppose 50, i don't get the number 50 posted, but when i type it after the number 50, then it is posted.

Comment: your ci version? also check your config file to 'global_xss_filtering' is false And your input 'type' for description is ?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter validation library for v3.1.4. Click [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)

Also use second parameter "true" for input filter:

```
$this->input->post('data', true);

$this->input->get('data', true);
```